# How to store data and display them in another view? Django

Tags: django, view

I have a simple sport events app. I log in as an user and I have a list of events I can join. When i join event, member value current_member is incremented. I have another view which contain list of events created by currently logged user. What I want to do more in this view is display also joined events. In my_events.hmtl (code below) i want to display in loop those events. How can I do it?

models.py

```
class Event(models.Model):
    SPORT = (
        ('Football', 'Football'),
        ('Volleyball', 'Volleyball'),
        ('Basketball', 'Basketball'),
        ('Futsal', 'Futsal'),
        ('Tennis', 'Tennis'),
        ('Handball', 'Handball'),
        ('Ice Hockey', 'Ice Hockey'),
        ('Paintball', 'Paintball')
    )
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    sport = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, choices=SPORT)
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    event_date = models.DateTimeField(default=date.today())
    end_event_date = models.DateTimeField(default=date.today())
    current_members = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    total_members = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    event_location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    cost = models.FloatField(default=0, max_length=5)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def join_event(request, pk):
    event = Event.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        event.current_members += 1
        if event.current_members <= event.total_members:
            event.save()
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Event is full!')
    context = {'event': event}
    return render(request, 'events/join_event.html', context)



@login_required(login_url='login')
def my_events(request):
    events = request.user.event_set.all()
    print('EVENTS', events)
    context = {'events': events}
    return render(request, 'events/my_events.html', context)
```

my_events.html

```
{%  extends 'events/main.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="card card-body">
        <h5>My own events</h5>
        <hr>
        <div class="card card-body">
            <table class="table table-sm">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>End Date</th>
                    <th>Location</th>
                    <th>Cost</th>
                    <th>Members</th>
                    <th>Update</th>
                    <th>Remove</th>

                </tr>

                {% for event in events %}
                <tr>
                    <th>{{event.event_name}}</th>
                    <th>{{event.event_date}}</th>
                    <th>{{event.end_event_date}}</th>
                    <th>{{event.event_location}}</th>
                    <th>{{event.cost}}</th>
                    <th>{{event.current_members}}/{{event.total_members}}</th>
                    <th>
                        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{% url 'update_event' event.id %}">
                            Update
                        </a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="{% url 'delete_event' event.id %}">
                            Delete
                        </a>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="card card-body">
        <h5>Joined events</h5>
        <hr>
        <div class="card card-body">
            <table class="table table-sm">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>End Date</th>
                    <th>Location</th>
                    <th>Cost</th>
                    <th>Members</th>
                    <th>Update</th>
                    <th>Remove</th>

                </tr>

                <!-- HERE I WANT TO DISPLAY IN FOR LOOP THOSE EVENTS LIKE ABOVE -->
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{%endblock content%}
```

Comment: Just tested my answer on my server, that works well.

Comment: I tried your code but joined events doesnt show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**Session**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#session-object-guidelines)

To save your data use: `request.session["joined_event"] = pk`

In another view to get your data: `request.session.get("joined_event")`

You can also save a list of ids in `request.session`

And you can try the following example:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def join_event(request, pk):
    event = Event.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        event.current_members += 1
        if request.session.get("joined_event"):
            request.session["joined_event"].append(pk)
        else:
            request.session["joined_event"] = [pk]
        if event.current_members <= event.total_members:
            event.save()
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Event is full!')
    context = {'event': event}
    return render(request, 'events/join_event.html', context)



@login_required(login_url='login')
def my_events(request):
    joined_event = request.user.event_set.filter(id__in=request.session.get("joined_event", []))
    events = request.user.event_set.all()
    print('EVENTS', events)
    context = {'events': events, 'joined_event': joined_event}
    return render(request, 'events/my_events.html', context)
```

Edit the MIDDLEWARE setting and make sure it contains
`'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'`

set `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST=True` in your settings.py

Your `request.session.get("key")` is also accessible in any other view.

Comment: It shows events created by this logged in user or events joined created by other users?

Comment: @mateuszj, It shows joined events by logged user. So joined events only for current logged user. Just try to use the above code

Comment: @mateuszj, Each user has his own session.

Comment: @mateuszj, have you added SessionMiddleware in your MIDDLEWARE?

Comment: Yes, I have. I just copy-pasted your example, but it does not show up joined events.

Comment: No, QuerySet joined_event is just empty, even when I join some events.

Comment: I have a typo in `request.user.evet_set`. It must be `request.user.event_set`. Did you adjust that?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that typo. It must be something else.

Comment: @mateuszj, I am using the same in my django application.

Comment: @mateuszj, Did you adjust that to "request.user.event_set"?

Comment: Yeah, it is exactly the same as above code.

Comment: If you print 'request.session.get ("joined_event")'. Do you see anything in console?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227817/discussion-between-nksm-and-mateuszj).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a many to many field related to users in Event, then you can add the user in the view and finally you can do a filter to show the Events like:

```
Event.objects.filter(users_joined = request.user).all()
```

Hope that could help you!.